# How can i fix a CORS error in Prolog making a request from Angular

Tags: angular, cors, prolog

I need some help in regards to making a POST request from my Angular application to my Prolog API.
I'm doing the request from Angular to Prolog.
I have enabled cors in Prolog but it still doesn´t work. I have used this like this in the past and it worked, now it doesn't.

I have checked and URL are okay.

```
:-use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:-use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:-use_module(library(http/json_convert)).
:-use_module(library(http/http_json)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_cors)).
:- use_module(library(strings)).

:-dynamic facto_index/1.

facto_index(1).

% CORS Enable
:- set_setting(http:cors, [*]).
:- cors_enable.



% Concatenates a StringList into a Bigger String
concatenate(StringList, StringResult) :-
    maplist(atom_chars, StringList, Lists),
    append(Lists, List),
    atom_chars(StringResult, List).

% Define a predicate to split a string using a specific character
split_string_helper(Input, Separator, Parts) :-
    split_string(Input, Separator, "", Parts).

% Starts the Server on port 7000
server :- server(7000).

% Stops the Server on port 7000
stop:- http_stop_server(7000,[]).

% Starts the Server on Port
server(Port):-
    http_server(http_dispatch,[port(Port)]).

% HTTP Routes
:- http_handler('/companyInfo',companyInfoData,[]).
:- http_handler('/inferenceEngine',inferenceEngine,[]).


companyInfoData(Request):-
       cors_enable(Request,[methods([post])]),
       carregarDados(Request),
       JSON = json(['success'='Yes']),
       reply_json(JSON).

inferenceEngine(Request):-
   cors_enable(Request,[methods([get])]),
   JSON = json(['success'='Yes']),
   reply_json(JSON).



% Loads data into output.pl File
carregarDados(Request):-
   http_read_json(Request,J), % Reads JSON from Request body
   json_to_prolog(J,L), % Transforms JSON into Prolog Fact
   OutputFile = 'output.pl', % Output file for facts
   open(OutputFile, write, OutStream), % Opens file for write
   getAtivosPassivos(L,OutStream), % Writes AtivosPassivos Facts into file
   getReditos(L,OutStream), % Writes Reditos Facts into file
   getGastosPerdas(L,OutStream), % Writes GastosPerdas Facts into file
   close(OutStream). % Closes File

%Ativos e Passivos

getAtivosPassivos(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('assetsLiabilities'=AtivosPassivos, L), % Same as member but for Variables
    getAtivos(AtivosPassivos,File),
    getCapitalProprio(AtivosPassivos,File),
    getPassivos(AtivosPassivos,File).

%Ativos

getAtivos(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('Assets'=A, L),
    getAtivosNaoCorrentes(A,File),
    getAtivosCorrentes(A,File),
    getTotal(A,File).

getAtivosNaoCorrentes(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('NonCurrentAssets'=ANC,L),
    process_json_objects(ANC,File).

getAtivosCorrentes(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('CurrentAssets'=AC,L),
    process_json_objects(AC,File).

getTotal(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('Total'=T,L),
    process_json_objects(T,File).

%Capital Proprio

getCapitalProprio(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('Equity'=CP,L),
    getCapitalEReservas(CP,File),
    getTotal(CP,File).

getCapitalEReservas(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('capitalAndReserves'=CR,L),
    process_json_objects(CR,File).

%Passivos

getPassivos(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('Liabilities'=P,L),
    getPassivosNaoCorrentes(P,File),
    getPassivosCorrentes(P,File),
    getTotal(P,File).

getPassivosNaoCorrentes(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('nonCurrentLiabilities'=PNC,L),
    process_json_objects(PNC,File).

getPassivosCorrentes(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('currentLiabilities'=PC,L),
    process_json_objects(PC,File).

%Reditos

getReditos(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('income'=C,L),
    process_json_objects(C,File).

%GastosPerdas

getGastosPerdas(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('expensesLosses'=GP,L),
    getCMVC(GP,File),
    getFSE(GP,File),
    getVariacao(GP,File),
    getGastosPessoal(GP,File),
    getOutrosGastos(GP,File),
    getProvisoes(GP,File),
    getTotal(GP,File).

getCMVC(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('CMVC'=CMVC,L),
    process_json_objects(CMVC,File).

getFSE(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('FSE'=FSE,L),
    process_json_objects(FSE,File).

getVariacao(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('Variation'=V,L),
    process_json_objects(V,File).

getGastosPessoal(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('StaffCosts'=GP,L),
    process_json_objects(GP,File).

getOutrosGastos(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('OtherExpenses'=OG,L),
    process_json_objects(OG,File).

getProvisoes(json(L),File):-
    memberchk('Provisions'=P,L),
    process_json_objects(P,File).



%JSON Processing Unit

process_json_objects([], _). % Empty List
process_json_objects(JsonObject, File):-  % When is only one JSON
    % Process the JSON object and write data to the file
    process_json_object(JsonObject,File).

process_json_objects([JsonObject | Rest], File):-  % When is a list of JSONs
    % Process the current JSON object and write data to the file
    process_json_object(JsonObject,File),
    % Continue processing the rest of the JSON objects
    process_json_objects(Rest, File).

process_json_object(json(Object),File):-
    Object = [Variable=json(Content)], % Gets the name of the JSON Object and the Content
    process_json_object_content(Variable,Content,File).


% For example if we send this (goodwill,valor-2020=1) we get this valor(goodwill,2020,1).
process_json_object_content(_,[],_).
process_json_object_content(Variable, [Var=Value | Rest], File) :-
    retract(facto_index(N1)),
    N is N1 + 1,
    asserta(facto_index(N)),
    split_string_helper(Var, "-", Parts), % Splits the Var by the -
    Parts = [H | T], % In the H the part before - and T after it

    (
    H = 'value',
    format(File, 'facto(~w,', N1),
    format(File, ' ~w(', H),
    format(File, '~w,', Variable),
    format(File, '~w,', T),
    format(File, '~w)).~n', Value),
    process_json_object_content(Variable, Rest, File);
      
    format(File, 'facto(~w,', N1),
    format(File, ' ~w(', H),
    format(File, '~w,', Variable),
    format(File, '~w)).~n', Value),
    process_json_object_content(Variable, Rest, File)
    ).
```

Request in Angular

```
uploadFileProlog(jsonString: any): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(`${PROLOG_API_URL}${PROLOG_API_UPLOAD_FILE}`,jsonString,{ headers });
  }
```

I have tried enabling cors

Comment: As a quick sanity check: Why are you using `_Request` instead of `Request`?

Comment: @brebs Yes mistake on my part. I have changed it to Request. Still not working